# Check user login in backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am making a URL shortener. Here is my code for it. I want limit some URLs open only for login users. Why this is not working

```
app.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { shortUrl } = req.params;
    const urlData = await URL.findOne({ shortUrl });

    if (urlData) {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const startDate = urlData.startDate ? new Date(urlData.startDate) : null;
      const expirationDate = urlData.expirationDate ? new Date(urlData.expirationDate) : null;
      const requireSignIn = urlData.requireSignIn || false;

      console.log('requireSignIn', requireSignIn);
      console.log('req.session.isLogged', req.session.isLogged);


      if (requireSignIn && req.session.isLogged === undefined) {
        return res.status(401).send('Please login to access this URL');
      }

      if (startDate === null && expirationDate === null) {
        // No start date and no expiration date, URL is accessible
        res.redirect(urlData.originalUrl);
      } else if (startDate !== null && startDate > currentDate) {
        // Start date is in the future, URL is not yet available
        res.status(400).send('Shortened URL is not available yet');
      } else if (expirationDate !== null && expirationDate < currentDate) {
        // Expiration date is in the past, URL has expired
        res.status(400).send('Shortened URL has expired');
      } else {
        // URL is accessible
        res.redirect(urlData.originalUrl);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('URL not found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error redirecting:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

this is how I save it on my login API

```
app.post('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
  // Clear isLogged from the session upon logout
  req.session.isLogged = false;
  req.logout(); // Optional: If you are using passport, you can also call req.logout() to remove the user from the session
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logout successful' });
});
```

I'm facing an issue where even after logging in, the application still prompts users to log in to access URLs marked as requiring sign-in. Can someone help me identify the problem and suggest a solution? Thank you!

THis is the log message

```
requireSignIn true
req.session.isLogged undefined
```